# Need Jquery to run action through url param just once

Tags: jquery

i have a link in my website that requires the user to be logged in. 
After he makes the login the page is redirected to where he was before and a param is set on the url - Jquery finds the param and triggers the link action. Until here everything is running fine.

The problem is if the user clicks the back button the param is still in the url and the jquery will trigger again the action. I tried to avoid that with history.replaceState and history.pushState functions giving a new url without the param but the browser still loads the page with the param when the user clicks the browser back button.

I also tried the sessionStorage function but it doesn't solve my problem.

Is there anything i could do with jquery to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, why are you mixing php and javascript for your redirect when you can do it straight from php?

Comment: Hi, thanks. The redirect is made with PHP. I only need to automatically trigger after that a action if the user comes from the login page.
http://www.example.com/page&triggerWishlist=true&otherStuff=false

Comment: I'm still not sure why you would want to use javascript, but you could set a session variable `just_logged_in`, add some js based on that and unset it right after that. Hard to tell though without seeing an example.

Comment: I see what you mean, the link i need to trigger is a modal, not an action. You're suggesting cookies?

Comment: You could probably get rid of all this if you handle the login through ajax, then you would not have to leave the page at all.

Comment: The login through ajax It's not a solution for now...